# Conditional Stop on Minizinc

Tags: minizinc

Thanks a lot for help .
There is User-defined behavior for stop contorl just like  “Stop after this many
solutions” , but is there any way to control Minizinc for following Conditional Stop

ex.
1 ) Stop after no more better solution for "10 min" .
which means for "slove minimize ..."  , if there is no more better solution in  "10 min"  , the computation will stop

2 ) Stop for the gap < 5% . this is used in MIP solver for stop .

thanks a lot .

PS , may be in javascript API ?

Conditional Stop on Minizinc

Comment: This is certainly something where MiniZinc has to be used programmatically. If you want the solvers to run natively, I would suggest you use MiniZinc Python, then you can use the `async` `Instance.solutions` method to inspect solutions and the statistics (including the gap) as they come in, and break if you are satisfied. The `asyncio` Python library should have the tools to add additional time limits

Comment: Thanks a lot  .  I am trying this way .